# PassportJS - Is it possible to change req.user for another user?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

In my application, I have implemented the ability to change a users permissions, rank, etc. It works great, if I update my own permissions, I can see the changes instantly since I can update the req.user object via `req.login()`. Problem is, when I update another users permissions, it updates in the database just fine, but the user will have to relog to see their permissions change since `req.user` still thinks they don't have the permission. This is fine if they're not logged in of course but if they are, I'd like the change to be reflected immediately for them if possible.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to update another users `req.user` object so they can see their permissions change right away without having to log out and back in?

Or possibly a way to logout and login that user before returning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the permissions are in your own database then sure you can, but how to do it depends on your app.

Given you are using sessions, object stored in `req.user` is loaded separately for every HTTP request by using the function you provided with `passport.deserializeUser`. Often you would store the user ID to the session in `passport.serializeUser`, and then retrieve the user from the database with the ID in `deserializeUser`. Thus, whenever a request is being handled in the backend you would generally have the latest information in `req.user`, including the permissions. Naturally your frontend also needs to somehow get the new permissions and adjust itself (eg. if you add admin rights to user, you probably would want them to see the admin options in the UI).

You could of course just pass the whole user object to the session store and skip one database call per request, ie. using these:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) { cb(null, user); });
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, cb) { cb(null, user); });
```

for session handling. If you do this then the database changes are not reflected upon the `req.user` object. If the user updated their own information you could just call `req.logIn(...)`, but that you cannot call for other users. You can work around this though - eg. notify the user in question over websocket and make their browser call a route that calls `req.logIn` with the latest user object, or dig into the session store and manipulate the data there directly.

Or, since forcing a logout is an option you could follow enRaisers answer and locate the users sessions from session store and delete them all which is effectively logging out the user from the backend. You can go through the sessions via the API, or if you use a database (eg. `connect-mongo` or `connect-redis`) for session store you can also open another connection to the same database and use normal search and destroy methods. Again you still need handle the logout in the frontend by yourself somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I changed my deserialize function to grab the user from the database and now `req.user` will update once the user refreshes the page. The more I think about it, I think the root of the problem is that I'm validating permissions based on `req.user` to avoid running a db look up every time someone does something permission based (which happens a lot). As someone more experienced than I, do you think it's fine to validate the users permissions using a db look up instead of trying to keep `req.user` updated all the time? This isn't exactly a huge application.

Comment: In general I would say that skipping a query where one item is fetched by it's ID is micro optimization, and hitting the DB in `deserializeUser` has never been an issue in my projects. I query-by-unique-id is the probably fastest query method in pretty much every database, and generally if you keep asking for same row again and again the database does something to speed things up. Just for reference, I queried a row by ID from my 14M line Postgres database and the first query was 65ms. Second query with same ID was 0.063ms.

Comment: True. Thanks for the advice! I ended up fixing the issue by changing my passport deserializing method to this: `passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});` which keeps `req.user` up to date. On the front end (Angular 1 in my case) I'm also updating the user on every route change by calling a route that returns `req.user` in order to keep the views updated. Hopefully this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to delete the session , or regenerated the sessionID. but this will force that user to re-login.

In case your sessions are stored in mongodb. then you can check collection by name **app_sessions** and it has a field by name **userId**.

in Express session there is a module called store. and it providea many API to find session by sessionID. but unfortunately no API to find session by userID.

So if you want to use the [session store API](https://github.com/expressjs/session) then  you can call store.all , which will give all session.   But this is really cruel method. becasue I dont know how much data it  may be holding.

Comment: I do use Mongodb but there's no collection with app_sessions in it.

Also from what I can tell, it looks like logging out the user would delete the session which is fine by me but how can I do that to another user?