# Can I force a session to update from the server side?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, session, connect-mongo

I have user profiles created by passport, which get stored in mongodb with connect-mongo. If i update the users profile for a session, I have to run `req.login()` to trigger passport to update the users session to match the new database info. If I change another user from my admin account I can't run this function, is there a way I can update it for the user, or trigger it to get updated the next time their session gets loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to do it all manually:

1. search sessions for one with matching user id
2. load latest user info and replace in session
3. save new info back to database

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

```
const SessionSchema = new Schema({_id: String}, { strict: false });
const Session = mongoose.model('sessions', SessionSchema, 'sessions');

var User = require('../queries/single.js');

module.exports = function (userId, callback) {

    console.log('finding session for',userId);

    Session.findOne({session: {$regex: userId}},null,{lean: true},(err, session)=>{
        if (err) return callback(err);
        if (!session) return callback('user session not found');

        //parse session
        var sessionJson = JSON.parse(session.session);

        //add reset flag
        sessionJson.passport.user.resetSession = true;

        //get updated user info
        User({_id: sessionJson.passport.user._id}, (err, updatedUser)=>{
            if (err) return callback(err);

            //add new user info to session json
            sessionJson.passport.user = updatedUser;

            //save back to session
            Session.findOneAndUpdate({_id: session._id},{$set: {session: JSON.stringify(sessionJson)}}, (err, savedSession) => {
                if (err) return callback(err);

                //success
                return callback(null);
            });

        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the whole user object to the session store which will ensure your user object is always up to date with the latest info.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) { cb(null, user); });
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, cb) { cb(null, user); });
```

Comment: My session already seems to contain a complete copy of the user object, it just doesn't get updated. What repercussions would this have?

Comment: Well with this serialization and deserialization technique, it'll run this every time the server receives a request from that user. A consequence of this is that it's making a call to the database every time, however I haven't had any issues with performance due to this and haven't seen anyone else have issues with it either.

I think your issue is similar to one I had a few years ago, see if this thread helps explain things better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193579/passportjs-is-it-possible-to-change-req-user-for-another-user