# NodeJS: Force user to refresh session after permissions have been changed by another user

Tags: node.js, express, session, passport.js

In my NodeJS application I use express-session for sessions, express-mysql-session to store the session to MariaDB, Passport for authentication and Sequelize for ORM.

The problem I have right now is that I do not know how to refresh a session of a user whose permissions have been changed by an admin of the application.

I tried something like `req.logIn()` but this refreshes only the session of the admin who is doing the permission changes.

My code looks like this:

```
editUser = function (req, res) {
    var userData.id = req.body.id;
    userdata.access = req.body.access;
    models.User.update(userData, {where: {id: userData.id}})
        .then(function (affectedRows) {
            // User has been updated.
            // Changes should be active without having the user to log out and log in again
        });
    );
}
```

Has anyone an idea how I can refresh the session of the user whose permissions have been changed by another user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for my problem at the following thread [PassportJS - Is it possible to change req.user for another user?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39199617/6808716)

I updated my `passport.deserializeUser()` to make a db request and reload the user. The queried user is then commited to the callback. The function now looks like this:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    models.User.findOne({where: {id: user.id}})
        .then(function(updatedUser) {
            done(null, updatedUser);
        }, function(err) {
            console.error(err);
            done(null, user);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`express-mysql-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mysql-session) needs a table and few fields configured to store the sessions info.

One of those fields is called `expires`.

If you set that field to `Date.now()`, the user should have its session expired.

**Update:**

After reading your comment and looking [through their code](https://github.com/chill117/express-mysql-session/blob/master/index.js#L219), we can see that the data stored in the session row in DB is a serialized JSON.

Since you're able to identify that user's session in the DB, you could also:

- read the session's data,
- `JSON.parse()` it,
- update the `.roles` array (the property where you
  keep user's role),
- `JSON.stringify()` it and save it back to DB.

Comment: This works but it is not the optimal solution for my problem. The user is being logged out and has to log in again.
I am searching for a solution where the user is not being logged out and the session is just refreshed with the new / changed informations.